# lua decrypted function get Error

Tags: lua

i'm new in Lua try to use [Base64 encoder/decoder](http://lua-users.org/wiki/BaseSixtyFour) functions when i try to print Data after using bdc( Decrypted Function )it give Errors

```
function bdc(data)
    data = string.gsub(data, '[^'..b..'=]', '')
    return (data:gsub('.', function(x)
        if (x == '=') then return '' end
        local r,f='',(b:find(x)-1)
        for i=6,1,-1 do r=r..(f%2^i-f%2^(i-1)>0 and '1' or '0') end
        return r;
    end):gsub('%d%d%d?%d?%d?%d?%d?%d?', function(x)
        if (#x ~= 8) then return '' end
        local c=0
        for i=1,8 do c=c+(x:sub(i,i)=='1' and 2^(8-i) or 0) end
        return string.char(c)
    end))
end
print(bdc('NjAgOTYgMDMgNjYgNDAgNjUgMDEgNkMgMDYgNjUgMDEgNkMgMDUgNjUgMDEgNkMgMDggNjUgMDEgNkMgMDk='))
```

**Error**

```
lua: data.lua:3: attempt to concatenate global 'b' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    data.lua:3: in function 'bdc'
    data.lua:16: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
```

Please Tell about Errors & why they Came?

Comment: Sounds like you missed the `local b='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/'` line from the original. You have no `b` global variable in your lua state.